# Kafka Stream: What happens to processor object when REBALANCE occur

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

> 1) We use Low level processor API.  When the rebalance occurs does the
>   processor object gets re-initialized and init method invoked again?
>
> 2) Is REBALANCE partition specific (single application having multiple
>   threads consuming different partitions) OR for the whole Kafka stream,
>   I assume later since it is a Stream state?

Answer (score 2):

> 1) We use Low level processor API. When the rebalance occurs does the
>   processor object gets re-initialized and init method invoked again?

In older versions (2.3.x or older), basically, when a StreamThread is started, it first triggers a rebalance, and after partitions are assigned, tasks are created and corresponding init() calls are made. For existing StreamThreads when a rebalance is triggered, all tasks are suspended (ie, calls to close() are made) and re-assigned as well as new tasks are started again.

In newer versions (2.4.x and newer), an incremental rebalancing is done and thus tasks are not suspended during a rebalance any longer.

> 2) Is REBALANCE partition specific (single application having multiple
>   threads consuming different partitions) OR for the whole Kafka stream,
>   I assume later since it is a Stream state?

You are right!! As quoted in this [blog](https://medium.com/streamthoughts/apache-kafka-rebalance-protocol-or-the-magic-behind-your-streams-applications-e94baf68e4f2):

> Kafka Streams uses it to assign tasks and partitions to the
>   application streams instances.

This blog talks about Kafka rebalancing and it's usage to assign to application stream instances.

Let me know if it helps!!